# Resize paragraph on button click

Tags: html, css, resize, paragraph

Good day,

Need your help guys. Is there a way to make a button `onclick` resize the paragraph's width in stylesheet? Basically it looks like this now:

```
p { width: 400px; }
```

My goal is, that the button will change it's width to 100%, so the paragraph will take the size of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest making a css class that has the paragraph width to be 100%.

Then use javascript (jquery, or plain) to add the css class to the element on button click.

[See this example](https://jsfiddle.net/e1hxctk7/7/)

```
fullWidthParagraph = function() {
  $('p').toggleClass('full-width');
 }
```

the `$('p')` selects all paragraph elements in the page, the `toggleClass` function adds/removes the `full-width` class on the elements. You can use `addClass` instead if you don't want the button to switch back and forth between the 400px and fullwidths.

Comment: Great solution @skrln, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

(I set `background-color:red` only you to see the changes)

```js
function changeP(){
 document.getElementById('p').style.width="100%";
}
```

```css
p { width: 400px;
    background-color:red; }
```

```html
<p id="p">Hello world</p>
<button onclick="changeP()">Try me</button>
```

Comment: Great solution if you want to resize one specific paragraph

Comment: you right i do it accordding question (next time post question with necessary requireds...)

Comment: It's all good. Now when a reader gets on this page, he will get solutions for both cases

Answer (score 0):

This will resize the `width` of your `p` element `onClick`:

```
<button type="button" onClick = "document.getElementById('text').style.width = '100%';">BUTTON TEXT</button>
    <p id="text" style="width: 400px;"></p>
```